# Codeigniter, проблема с плагином HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

Добрый день.

В общем поставил чистый codeigniter. Создал модуль где есть запрос к бд
http://moodle.riskk.kz/index.php/tm/testmod/secondmethod

```
public function secondmethod()
    {

        $dbq = $this->db->select('test')->from('test')->get()->row()->test;
        echo 'testmod second - '.$dbq;
    }
```

И он работает когда обращаешься к нему напрямую, но если вызвать его с контроллера
http://moodle.riskk.kz/

```
public function index()
    {
      echo modules::run('tm/testmod/secondmethod');
         //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
```

то получаю ошибку

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: testmod::$db

Filename: controllers/testmod.php

Line Number: 16
Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in /var/www/riskk.kz.moodle/application/modules/tm/controllers/testmod.php on line 16
```

В общем вся проблема в том что модуль обращается к бд, но зачем мне юзать hmvc и модульность если не будут работать запросы к бд.

Даже не знаю в какую сторну копать :(

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, вся проблема в том что раз ставишь плагин HMVC то контроллеры должны наследоваться от MX_Controller, слава богу переход на Yii||Kohana||RoR откладываеться!!!